# Are there any good alternatives to Apache Ignite as an In-Memory Data Grid used together with Spring as a distributed cache?

Tags: spring, hazelcast, druid, in-memory-data-grid

We have a solution which uses the Apache Ignite-provided In-Memory Data Grid as a distributed cache. For newer projects, we ended up using Spring, and as such we wished homogenize our software ecosystem and using Spring for the first solution as well. In addition, we do not use all the features of Ignite to excuse its use (discovery, caching).

Since we currently only use a limited subset of features from Ignite, we are basically looking for a self-managed application-level distributed cache solution (similar to what Ignite provides). This means that dedicated caching infrastructure like Redis, Memcached, etc. is not what we want.

I've researched the topic somewhat and found that there are some possible alternatives like:

- [Tayzgrid](http://www.alachisoft.com/tayzgrid/) - Last update seems to be quite some time ago, not sure if still actively maintained
- [Druid](http://druid.io/) - Still incubating, and I have also read that new releases being somewhat broken was not that uncommon
- [Hazelcast](https://hazelcast.com/use-cases/imdg/) - Seems like the best choice given its maturity and the existence of [Spring Data Hazelcast](https://github.com/hazelcast/spring-data-hazelcast), though I am unsure what the level of support is here.

Has anyone has experience with integrating one of the above IMDGs (aside from Ignite) with Spring Cache? Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hazelcast has official support for [Spring Data Hazelcast](https://github.com/hazelcast/spring-data-hazelcast) and also this module has many users as now. I can also suggest you to have a look at the resources below:

[Using Hazelcast with Spring Data](https://hazelcast.com/resources/spring-data-hazelcast/)

[Getting Started with Microservices Using Hazelcast IMDG and Spring Boot](https://hazelcast.com/resources/microservices-with-hazelcast/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Redisson](https://redisson.org) - Redis Java client with features of
In-Memory Data Grid. It also implements Spring Data support. Here is [the documentation](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/tree/master/redisson-spring-data).